# What does the data returned by scipy.io.wavfile.read mean?

Tags: python, scipy, wav

The documentation of `scipy.io.wavfile.read` says that it returns sample rate and data. But what does data actually mean here in case of `.wav` files?

Can anyone let me know in layman terms how that data is prepared?

PS. I read somewhere that it means amplitude? Is what I read correct? If yes, how is that amplitude calculated and returned by `scipy.io.wavfile.read`?

Answer (score 2):

`scipy.io.wavfile.read` is a convenience wrapper to decompose the `.wav` file into a header and the data contained in the file.

From the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/wavfile.py)

```
Returns
-------
rate : int
    Sample rate of wav file.
data : numpy array
    Data read from wav file.  Data-type is determined from the file;
    see Notes.
```

Simplified code from the source:

```
fid = open(filename, 'rb')
try:
    file_size, is_big_endian = _read_riff_chunk(fid) # find out how to read the file
    channels = 1 # assume 1 channel and 8 bit depth if there is no format chunk
    bit_depth = 8
    while fid.tell() < file_size: #read the file a couple of bytes at a time
        # read the next chunk
        chunk_id = fid.read(4)

        if chunk_id == b'fmt ':  # retrieve formatting information
            fmt_chunk = _read_fmt_chunk(fid, is_big_endian)
            format_tag, channels, fs = fmt_chunk[1:4]
            bit_depth = fmt_chunk[6]
            if bit_depth not in (8, 16, 32, 64, 96, 128):
                raise ValueError("Unsupported bit depth: the wav file "
                                 "has {}-bit data.".format(bit_depth))
        elif chunk_id == b'data':
            data = _read_data_chunk(fid, format_tag, channels, bit_depth,is_big_endian, mmap)

finally:
    if not hasattr(filename, 'read'):
        fid.close()
    else:
        fid.seek(0)

return fs, data
```

The data itself is usually PCM represented sound pressure levels in successive frames for the different channels. The sampling rate returned by `scipy.io.wavfile.read` is necessary to determine how many frames represent a second.

A good explanation of the `.wav` format is offered by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039846/what-do-the-bytes-in-a-wav-file-represent).

scipy doesn't calculate much on its own.