# extract data from .wav file

Tags: python, wav

i have [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A-DO712X2xxoMS7LW6mrE5JGhVhi_yYe) .wav file containing an ECG signal , Iwant to extract the data in that file using  `scipy.io.wavfile.read('sig100.wav')`
but I got this error

> "has {}-bit data.".format(bit_depth))
>
> ValueError: Unsupported bit depth: the wav file has 11-bit data.

As I was doing some research on this I found out that that function only accepts 8-bit depth file , but I can't figure out how to modify it to accept my file I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399930/what-does-the-data-returned-by-scipy-io-wavfile-read-mean) on stackoverflow but didn't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [scipy.io.wavfile source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/wavfile.py) , it accepts (8, 16, 32, 64, 96, 128) bit data.

While you can modify wavfile source code to accept the data, an easier alternative is to use external libraries like `pydub` . See API and installation details [here.](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#installation)

First, we take your file, convert bitrate to 16bit and export it.
Then, simply import modified wav file using `scipy` to get data and frame-rate.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio = "sig100.wav"
audio1 = "sig100_16.wav"

#read wav file and export with 16bit bitrate
s = AudioSegment.from_file(audio, format = "wav" )
s.export(audio1 , bitrate="16", format="wav")

#read modified file
rate, data = wavfile.read(audio1)
```

Result:

```
>>> rate
360
>>> data
array([[ -928,  -416],
       [ -928,  -416],
       [ -928,  -416],
       ...,
       [-4320, -2336],
       [-4896, -2144],
       [-8192,     0]], dtype=int16)
>>>
```

Hope this helps.