# Return type of wavfile.read in python

Tags: python, audio, wav

I need to analyse a sound file, in order to get when the sound is louder.

I have this :

> rate, data = wavfile.read('test.wav')

I know the meaning of the rate value, but what really is in the data variable ?

It works well when I want to retrieve the time intervals of the louder part of the audio, by looking at the data list, but I can't really find out the meaning of this list...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data holds a numpy array representing the sound in your .wav file.
Some good explanations on how the sound is represented in that data can be found in the following question: 
[What do the bytes in a .wav file represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039846/what-do-the-bytes-in-a-wav-file-represent)

Answer (score 0):

`data` in [wav files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is [audio samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)). Most of the time it's 16bit signed integers. For wav files you mostly care about rate (sound frequency) and number of channels (if your wav file is not mono).