# Java - What do the Bytes Recieved by Reading from an AudioInputStream Correspond to?

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound, audioinputstream

Can someone explain what the bytes you get by reading an AudioInputStream correspond to? Things like volume or frequency/pitch. I have this code that reads the bytes from the entire file.

```
int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead = -1;
while ((bytesRead = audioStream.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
  for(byte b:bytesBuffer)
    System.out.print(b+" ");
  System.out.println();
}
```

Currently I am trying to get the maximum volume in the sound file I have. It is a 16 bit PCM wav file.

Comment: This post should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039846/what-do-the-bytes-in-a-wav-file-represent

Comment: Oracle sound tutorial info covering this is here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html
To maximize volume, the entire PCM (sets assume signed shorts) set would be multiplied by a single factor that results in products that lie in between -32767 and 32767. Exceeding that leads to pretty obnoxious distortion pretty quickly.

Comment: So from what I understand, all of the bytes are for amplitude/volume?

Comment: I did some testing and it's every other byte that relates to volume. I still don't know what the other bytes are for though.

Comment: The two bytes are concatenated into a single PCM value ranging to all values held by a signed short. That is why it is called 16-bit (each byte is 8 bits). This info is in the tutorial linked in an earlier comment. Your sample rate tells how many frames are in one second. Given a Format (tells you how many bytes per frame, related to number of tracks and number of bits per track) you can tell the timing via counting bytes.

Comment: What I did was skip the first 44 bytes then to get the volume I did
```AIS.read(bytesBuffer);
                for(int i=1;i<bytesBuffer.length;i+=2){
                    B = Math.abs((int)bytesBuffer[i]);
                    if(max<B)max = B;
                }```
to get the volume. I only read every other byte. Are the other bytes for frequency/pitch? Sorry I can't figure out how to make this code not inline.